# BSD grep does not stop after executing

Tags: bash, grep

**I am using BSD grep!** (Different from UNIX grep)
    grep -e '22T1[2-4]' nagoya_all.csv -> nagoya12_14.csv

When I execute this command, `nagoya12_14.csv` is successfully created. However, on terminal is doesn't prompt me for a new command.

Why does this happen?
How can i check if this command is still running?

Comment: Actually: grep (GNU grep) 2.25: `grep 'foo' -`; type `'fooled'`, hit RETURN, and then ^D (Ctrl-D, aka End-of-File, EOF) and see what happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take out the `-` in front the redirect sign `>` and you should be good. When you have `-` at the end of a grep command, it will try to read from stdin, which waits for user input.

Comment: Not just at the end: If you tell `grep` to read from a file called `-`, it will process standard input. E.g. `grep 'regex' - foo.csv` will also work (i.e. wait for you to type something until you hit Ctrl-D to signal end-of-file).

Comment: You are right about the position of the `-` but I think in your example you are missing the pattern - the example you intended to give is `grep pattern - foo.csv` I believe.

Comment: While this answer is correct, out of curiosity, @leonard, why was that `-` placed before `>`?